# Splitting a list F Sharp

Tags: list, f#

I'm trying to write a method that splits a list into two.  The function should return a tuple of the two lists and the arguments that the function takes are the # of items on the first list, and then the list.  Here's what I mean

list [1,2,3,4]

split(1,list)-> ([1],[2,3,4])
split (3,list) -> ([1,2,3],[4])

Here's what I have so far:

```
let rec mysplit = function
  |(n,[])->([],[])
  |(1,x::xs)->(x::[],xs)
  |(n,x::xs)->  mysplit(n-1,xs)
```

I'm not exactly sure how to "catch" the tuple back from the recursive call.  Not sure where to have an extra let statement in there to temporarily save the list I'm building up. New to the language so a couple of different approaches would be good to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A straightforward implementation would be:

```
let rec mysplit = function
  |(n,[])->([],[])
  |(1,x::xs)->(x::[],xs)
  |(n,x::xs)->  let (f, s) = mysplit(n-1,xs) in (x::f, s)
```

You could also write a tail-recursive version:

```
let mysplit (n, l) = 
    let rec mysplit' n' (f, s) = function
    | [] -> (f, s)
    | (x::xs) as l' -> if n' = 0 then (f, l') else mysplit' (n'-1) (x::f, xs) xs

    let (f', s) = mysplit' n ([], []) l in (List.rev f', s)
```

Answer (score 7):

Skip and take are your friends here. I don't think you need to do any sort of matches or recursive calls when there's a direct approach.

```
let split n l = (l |> Seq.take n, l |> Seq.skip n)
```

As for possible edge cases, skip will return an empty sequence if there are `> n` elements in the list, and take will return the first n elements if there are `< n` elements in the sequence.

Tried it in TryFharp.org with your examples and it works as expected.

Comment: Now that's what I call f# 

Answer (score 0):

Lee's answer shows you a working solution, but to answer your specific question, you can capture values returned to you in a tuple like so:

```
let before, after = mysplit (2, [1;2;3;4;5])
```

You can also use this trick to declare multiple variables in a single let statement:

```
let i, j, k = (1, 2, 3)
```